# How can I unmute (and turn off autoplay) a YouTube video for twentyseventeen?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have [a lecture on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dYAYBNU6qM) that I would like to use as the header movie for [my twentyseventeen child themed website.](https://cjshayward.com) I would like it with sound and without autoplay (As viewed on YouTube, the video has sound intact).

Following another question about autoplay, I set a video URL of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dYAYBNU6qM&autoplay=0. The behavior does not appear to have changed. It starts immediately, but sound is muted.

How, with twentyseventeen, do I have an option of a media file that starts paused, and begins to play, with sound, if the user hits the 'Play' button?

Comment: it's default WordPress bug they set video autoplay by default if you want to stop that then you have to change core JS file /wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.min.js fine autoplay:1 replace it with autoplay:0 then it stop autoplay

Comment: how are you embedding the video - can you show the html/php?

Comment: because it seems like your iframe has : allow="autoplay" - and your URL has autoplay=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `global` object `wp` for get access to youtube player functions. Youtube video in `twentyseventeen theme` loads [wp-custom-header.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js#L384) file and creating new object in 384 line.

Here is some solution you can use:

```
var ww_timer = setTimeout(function ww_video() {
    if(wp.customHeader.handlers.youtube.player == null){
        ww_timer = setTimeout(ww_video, 50);
    }else {
        if(typeof wp.customHeader.handlers.youtube.player.unMute === "function") {
            wp.customHeader.handlers.youtube.player.unMute();
            wp.customHeader.handlers.youtube.player.stopVideo();
        }else{
            ww_timer = setTimeout(ww_video, 50);
        }
    }
}, 50);
```

This code goes to `my_js.js` file( I created it in the main directory of active child theme. You can add this code to another `.js`, if you have it ) of your active child theme. Also, we need to update `functions.php` file using this code:

```
function ww_youtube_functions(){
  wp_enqueue_script('ww_youtube_video',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_js.js',array('wp-custom-header'),false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ww_youtube_functions');
```

Required part of this code is `array('wp-custom-header')`: enqueue script with dependence with script `wp-custom-header`.

`setTimeout` is not best way. I believe, that it can be done with more elegant code.

But its tested and working.

Comment: Thank you; I have looked briefly and don't see where a theme's my_js.js file belongs. Does it go in the root of the theme? Someplace else? Thanks...

Comment: @JonathanHayward I created `my_js.js` file in the main directory of child theme. instead of it you can use another `.js` file. in that case, you should change this code: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_js.js'` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/{your-js-file-name.js}'`