# How to unmute wordpress fvplayer video on autoplay

Tags: wordpress

I am using fvplayer plugin for video display in my wordpress site. I have uploaded a video but it is displaying in "MUTE" condition. And i want it to be played "UNMUTE", What should I do? Please share some solution. Below is the screenshot of my fvplayer setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted their support team and they told me that "Google chrome has restricted autoplay video sound, so google chrome itself mute it." So I removed autoplay in the video and it is perfectly playing when played manually.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to unmute via JS. 
i think its muted by default in Wordpress.

This link might help you. 
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362721/how-can-i-unmute-and-turn-off-autoplay-a-youtube-video-for-twentyseventeen)

Even Though it is for Youtube Videos.

Answer (score 0):

there is the problem with the browser that if you unmute the video them it can autoplay but if it is not muted it does not start automatically.
Try to change the chrome to firefox. I think their Spyder Monkey can support autoplay instead of V8 from Google